# AngularJS - Display only objects that share a team

Tags: jquery, angularjs

so I am trying to separate from all my objects only those that are on the same team. Each object has the following structure:

```
{"first_name":"Bob","last_name":"Sagat","username":"bobsagat",
"email":"bob@fake.com","playerTeam":"TestTeam"}
```

how can I query just the objects where playerTeam = TestTeam?

Comment: `items | filter:{playerTeam:'TestTeam'}:true`.

Comment: So how would I implement that in a listview? on the JS side or in the html?

Comment: In your HTML, in your `ngRepeat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

items | filter:{playerTeam:'TestTeam'}:true in my ngRepeat worked thanks.